# Xamarin.iOS - Could not install package 'System.Net.Http 4.0.0' the package does not contain any assembly references

Tags: ios, xamarin, nuget, httpclient, system.net

I am trying to install the NuGet package System.Net.Http on my IOS project. But running into this error:

> Error: Could not install package 'System.Net.Http 4.0.0'. You are
>   trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author

I use the HttpClient in my SharedProject to download and parse a webpage. I can add the reference to the IOS package, but when I debug the project the HttpClient is always a "Unknown identifier".

My Solution runs perfekt in Android, Universal App and Windows Phone 8.1

I am using VS2015.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by installing the package in Xamarin Studio, and then switched back to Visual Studio.